# Why distinct() is not working in my sqldatasource?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWPzF.png)[image][image]I want to display timetable to faculty i.e they will have different batch allocated to them with same date but i want to display in single grid view.I have tried with distinct but its not working.They will have first hour and second hour with different batch and i want to display there subject and batch in single column but its showing in two column in single grid view. please help me out from these problem

```
<label>From Date</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="fromdate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<label>To Date</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="todate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="viewid" runat="server" OnClick="viewid_Click" Text="View" CssClass="button2"/>
<asp:GridView ID="Viewsubjects" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="batch1" CssClass="mGrid1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datedif" HeaderText="datedif" SortExpression="datedif" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1" SortExpression="subject1">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("subject1")!=DBNull.Value ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Subject:"+Eval("subject1")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="label6" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("batch")!=DBNull.Value && Eval("subject1")!=DBNull.Value) ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Batch:"+Eval("batch")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2" SortExpression="subject2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("subject2")!=DBNull.Value ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Subject:"+Eval("subject2")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="label7" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("batch")!=DBNull.Value && Eval("subject2")!=DBNull.Value) ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Batch:"+Eval("batch")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3" SortExpression="subject3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("subject3")!=DBNull.Value ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Subject:"+Eval("subject3")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="label8" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("batch")!=DBNull.Value && Eval("subject3")!=DBNull.Value) ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Batch:"+Eval("batch")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4" SortExpression="subject4">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("subject4")!=DBNull.Value ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Subject:"+Eval("subject4")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="label9" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("batch")!=DBNull.Value && Eval("subject4")!=DBNull.Value) ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Batch:"+Eval("batch")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5" SortExpression="subject5">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("subject5")!=DBNull.Value ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Subject:"+Eval("subject5")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="label10" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("batch")!=DBNull.Value && Eval("subject5")!=DBNull.Value) ? true:false %>' Text='<%#"Batch:"+Eval("batch")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="batch1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1ConnectionString1 %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [datedif], [subject1], [subject2], [subject3], [subject4], [subject5],[batch] FROM [test] WHERE ([datedif] &gt;= @datedif)">
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="fromdate" Name="datedif" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

These is how am getting the output

[image]

Comment: What rows does your SQL `SELECT` statement return? Can you check if those are in fact distinct?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT [datedif], [subject1], [subject2], [subject3], [subject4], [subject5],[batch] FROM [test] WHERE  datedif between '"+fromdate1.text+"' and '"+todate1.text+"'. these is the query i have used to display some particular value.

Comment: see my table above u will get some idea

Comment: That's a really bad table design. Having repeating columns distinguished just by number if usually a sign that there should be *one* of each column but more rows. Don't design a table based on how the information happens to be *presented*. The current design is really bad if you need, for instance, to find all entries with the subject `LINER TRADE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these queries given below-

```
create table timetable1(date date,hour1 int,subject1 varchar(255),batch1 varchar(20),hour2 int,subject2 varchar(255),batch2 varchar(20),hour3 int,subject3 varchar(255),batch3 varchar(20),faculty varchar(255));

insert into timetable1 values(cast(getdate() as date), 1, 'subject1','B1',0, 's2','b2',3,'s3','b3','ms. hart');
insert into timetable1 values(cast(getdate() as date), 1, 'subject12','B12',0, 's12','b12',3,'s13','b13','ms. hart11');
insert into timetable1 values(cast(getdate() as date), 1, 'subject13','B122',0, 's222','b222',3,'s23','b23','ms. hart22');  

select date,(subject1+' '+batch1) as hour1, (subject2+' '+batch2) as hour2,(subject3+' '+batch3) as hour3,faculty from timetable1group by date, faculty,subject1,subject2,subject3,batch1,batch2,batch3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i got the output

Comment: @RavintherM : Then you should pay the bounty !!

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting IS actually distinct, because each row has different values.  What you're looking for is a "group by", which will group your values by day and faculty.  My solution is based on replacing your current solution of:

```
date       hour1   subject1     hour2   subject2    hour3   subject3    faculty
2015-06-25  1      subject 1    0       (null)      0       (null)      ms. hart
2015-06-25  0      (null)       1       subject 2   0       (null)      ms. hart
2015-06-25  0      (null)       0       (null)      1       subject 3   ms. hart
```

with:

```
date        hour1       hour2       hour3       faculty
|----------|----------|-----------|-----------|----------|
2015-06-25  subject 1   subject 3   subject 3   ms. hart
```

If this is assumption is correct, then here is the query I used (I created my own tables because you did not provide DDL but if you have issues let me know)

```
select date,max(subject1) hour1, max(subject3) hour2, max(subject3) hour3, faculty from timetable
group by date, faculty
```

And here is the sql fiddle for you to experiment :)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1850/3

Comment: but i want the batch also in that also

Comment: You know how to add columns to a query, correct? Because that's all you have to do.

Comment: I have five faculty such as faculty1,faculty2,faculty3,faculty4,faculty5.i want output for only particular  faculty can some one suggest me some idea